# Grails - Hibernate mapping with self referenced table

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hibernate-mapping, self-reference

I'm upgrade the grails version of my app from 1.3.7 to 2.2.4 and now a spiritual bug is haunting myself.

If I take off the dateCreated property works fine. I try use the beforeInsert, but the problem is the same.

I have a self referenced entity like the small example below:

```
Class Employee {
    Date dateCreated
    Name name
    Employee brother
}
```

I use xml hibernate mapping file and that relationship is represented like this

```
<property name="dateCreated" column="dateofcreation" not-null="false"/>
<many-to-one name="brother" column="brother" cascade="save-update" fetch="join"/>
```

The problem is... when I try to save the employee and the brother at the same time using the save(flush: true) from Grails as below

```
void testSaveEmployeeAndBrother() {
    Employee e1 = new Employee('employee')
    Employee e2 = new Employee('brother')
    e1.brother = e2
    e2.brother = e1
    assert e1.save(flush: true)
}
```

I have the follow error message:

```
Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into employee (name, brother, id) values (?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into employee (name, brother, id) values (?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at EmployeeTests.testSaveEmployeeAndBrother(EmployeeTests.groovy:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Entrada em lote 0 insert insert into employee (name, brother, id) values ('brother', '1', '2') foi abortada. Chame getNextException para ver a causa.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1837)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2754)
    ... 1 more
```

I use grails 2.2.4, jdk-1.7.0_40, postgres 9.2

Comment: We would like to see what it says after `... 1 more`

Comment: Thanks..
In hibernate log I have this message: ERROR main org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: insert or update on table "employee" violates foreign key constraint "fkey_brother_id"
  Detalhe: Key (brother)=(1) is not present in table "employee".

Comment: The problem is because my class have the dateCreated property, removing this property the test works, but I don't know yet how solve this problem. I update the example with this discovery.

Comment: Today I receive an answer in Jira: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10523